# How would I change the Platform setting of an Azure App service from DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

Specifically, I'm trying to change the Platform of a .NET webapp to 64-bit via AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4 but can't find a good example.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  displayName: 'Azure App Service Deploy'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '$(AzureSubscription)'
    WebAppName: '$(AppServiceName)'
    ConfigurationSettings: '-use32BitWorkerProcess false'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Azure Devops
[AzureAppServiceSettings@1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-app-service-settings-v1?view=azure-pipelines) task to configure the **General settings** of the App Service.

```
- task: AzureAppServiceSettings@1
  displayName: Azure App Service Settings
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
    generalSettings: |
    [
     {
      "use32BitWorkerProcess": false
     }
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks but my question was for `AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4`.